# excluding a class from style

Tags: css

I'm trying to style all html with the class called sample

```
<div class="sample">
</div>

.sample{

}
```

But I'm running into a situation where the class sample could be nested. In this case I want to style only the inner one. How can I tell the css to apply the style only to the inner div and not to the outer sample? Can this be done?

```
<div class="sample">
   <div class="sample">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **descendant** selector for your ruleset:

```
.sample .sample
```

If you want to maintain the style on your outer `div`, then I'd suggest giving it another class, like

```
.something .sample
```

Using the same class for *all* the elements on a page is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Child Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors):

```
div>.sample {}
```

or:

```
div.sample>.sample {}
```

Comment: NB the child selector ">" is not supported by IE6.  Ref http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/

Comment: workarounds, for "the nearly dead one": http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/19/emulating-css-child-selectors-in-ie6/